# how to display custom dowpdown with custom values in admin grid of magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I am trying to display custom dropdown in admin grid of Magento.
i have added in database `income_source` attribute as a enum. with values 'C' 'I' and after saving this I want to display it on admin panel grid with label 'customer''incentives' .

I have added this code in 
protected function `_prepareColumns()` function

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('contactus/contactus')->getAttribute('wel_contactus', 'income_sourcer');
$options = array();
foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option )     {
   $options[$option['C']] = $option['Customer'];
   $options[$option['I']] = $option['Incentives'];
}
$this->addColumn('income_source',
array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('contactus')->__('Income Source'),
    'width' => '80px',
    'index' => 'income_source',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'options' => $options,
));
```

But it showing error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object.
>   thanks in advance.

Comment: fatal error is because you are not getting proper data in `$attribute`

Comment: so how to get data in  $attrubute

Comment: in which table you have saved your data?

Comment: i  have save this data in custom module with custom table name as 'contactus'

Comment: can i add all this code in grid.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this-

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('contactus/contactus')->getCollection();
$options = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($collections as $key => $value) {
    $i++;
    $options[$value->getYourTableColumn()] = $value['your_table_column'];
}

$this->addColumn('income_source',
array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('contactus')->__('Income Source'),
    'width' => '80px',
    'index' => 'income_source',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'options' => $options,
));
```

Or If you want the option to be fixed then you can do like this-

```
$this->addColumn('income_source',
array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('contactus')->__('Income Source'),
    'width' => '80px',
    'index' => 'income_source',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'options' => array(
                'C' => 'Customer',
                'I' => 'Incentives',
            ),
));
```